# How to properly InsertAllOnSubmit() and is that better than looping InsertOnSubmit()?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, ienumerable

Say I have:

```
using (SomeDataContext db = new SomeDataContext())
{

     foreach(Item i in Items)
     {
          DbItem d = new DbItem;
          d.value = i.value;
          //.... etc ...

          db.InsertOnSubmit(d);
     }

     db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Is it possible and/or better (worse?) to do:

```
using (SomeDataContext db = new SomeDataContext())
{
     IEnumerable<DbItem> dbItems = //???? possible?

     foreach(Item i in Items)
     {
          DbItem d = new DbItem;
          d.value = i.value;
          //.... etc ...

          dbItems.Add(d); // ???? again, somehow possible?
     }

     db.InsertAllOnSubmit(dbItems);
     db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well you could use `List<T>`:

```
using (SomeDataContext db = new SomeDataContext())
{
     List<DbItem> dbItems = new List<DbItem>();

     foreach(Item i in Items)
     {
          DbItem d = new DbItem;
          d.value = i.value;
          //.... etc ...

          dbItems.Add(d);
     }

     db.InsertAllOnSubmit(dbItems);
     db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Whether that will be any more efficient or not, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I was thrown off by the intellisense for saying the input type was IEnumerable.

Answer (score 4):

You won't see any performance improvement here, because nothing happens until you call `SubmitChanges()`.

But even if you were doing something ugly like this

```
foreach(Item i in Items)      
{           
    DbItem d = new DbItem;           
    d.value = i.value;           
    //.... etc ...            
    db.InsertOnSubmit(d);      
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I wouldn't expect any significant performance decrease. This is because LINQ-to-SQL does singular inserts.

Even if you use `InsertAllOnSubmit`, you'll still see a separate SQL Command for **each** row being inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Not saying that it is better or worse but anytime you can make a single database call vs. calling a database in a loop you will see a performance increase.  Now what `.SubmitChanges()` does behind the scenes is something out of our control.